# Implementing a horizontal date scroller using RecyclerView

Tags: android, calendar, android-recyclerview, scroller

This is what I'm trying to get:
[image: click here(Link) for image]

This is what I'm getting:
[image: Click here(Link)]

I'm struggling with implementing the "lift" effect. I've tried using `RecyclerView` but failed to implement it!

Comment: Search Carousel View for Android, it will do the trick for you

Answer (score 0):

it it not possible with recyclerview to  achieve this type of calender view so i suggest you to use this library [horizontal calender view](https://github.com/Mulham-Raee/Horizontal-Calendar)

Comment: I've tried that library it has some problem with number of items/screen

Comment: you van achieve this using Carousel  layout  for particular data like one moth or two month

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question. Please check with the image.

Comment: Is Carousel layout can accept more than 5 items at a time..?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `RecyclerView` with `LinearLayoutManager` and you need to set the layout manager's orientation to `HORIZONTAL`.

You could also add a field to the adapter to save the currently selected item's position, and have an special effect for that item in the rendering part.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question. Please check with the image.

Comment: I'm using recyclerview with LinearLayout and Horizontal orientation.

Comment: From your image , it seems you are very close to the final image but the height is not right. check the RecyclerView's height and also the height of each view you pass to the adapter. (check for `match_parent` as layout height and convert it to `wrap_content`)

Comment: also to get rid of the clipped shadows in your items, add this to the layout of the children views: `android:clipChildren="false"` and `android:clipToPadding="false"`